# How can I absolutely position an element via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I have a div nested in a td and the div class is set to absolute:

```
.mouseover-tooltip {
    width:400px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid #555;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;
    box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    left:-9999px;
    padding:5px;
    display: none;
}
```

But when I give it a top of 0, it aligns itself with the top of it's parent. That's not what I want. I want to work in an absolute world.

Comment: It positions itself inside its closest non-static positioned ancestor, which may or may not be it's actual parent. You can either do some calculations of the position of that ancestor and use negative positioning values or you can move the item to be a child of the `BODY` and leave a placeholder in the cell.

Comment: how do you set the position? maybe try inspecting with chrome or firebug and see if the `div` is really absolute or not (and if not, wich css directive is overriding your css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I give it a top of 0, it aligns itself with the top of it's parent.

That's how [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position) works: relative to the offset parent.<sup>1</sup> From your statement I can infer that the element's parent is positioned.<sup>2</sup>

Use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset#offset2) to set the position of the element relative to the document, or change the HTML structure such that the element's offset parent is the `<body>`.

---

<sub>1. The closest positioned ancestor or the containing block.</sub>
<sub>2. That is, the parent has computed `position` of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`.</sub>